Geometry not casting or receiving shadows... when linked?
all. I'm working on an environment that's used across multiple scenes and I've got a weird issue.
In the referenced environment, this little stool thing receives and casts shadows. It has the same material as the carpet underneath it, too. (See image 1 below.) The original file has no lights but I've added some to show exactly what I'm working with.
But when I link this into a new blender file there don't appear to be any shadows cast on the geometry. There also appears to be a little difference in how the copied & pasted Point light appears between Image 1 and 2. It seems cooler in Image 2. But that's not really the issue... why does my geometry get excluded from light data when linked? This has me baffled!
Image 1: environment in original file.

Image 2: environment when linked (same light and camera setup).


Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is harder to read and may be considered rude. Please use the [edit] button below the post to change your text into regular case.
